# Which JavaScript framework have anybody used with CodeIgniter?

Tags: codeigniter, dojo

I've delved into [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit) which I intend to use with [CodeIgniter](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EllisLab#CodeIgniter).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Any JavaScript framework should work with your server side programing language without any issues.

Thus [jQuery](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JQuery), [Ext](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext_%28JavaScript_library%29), [YUI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Yahoo!_UI_Library), [Dojo Toolkit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dojo_Toolkit), etc. should all work just fine.

Is there something in particular that you'd like to do that you'd like to know if a certain library would excel at?

Comment: I've been more involved in Dojo because of their components - Dijit. Similar things has Ext also, even more so. I'm more and more into js-libraries which are more like components. With another words doing web apps that feel almost like desktop apps - a little like office style.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can use any javascript framework in codeigniter. You see in your views you can put in anything including javascript, css, html css and even php.

[And this link is going to help you much.](http://www.codeofficer.com/blog/entry/codeigniter_javascript_library/)

thanks

Answer (score 0):

Qcubed or Codeigniter + Dojo